# Polchinski's No-Ghost Proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I'm struggling to understand an aspect of Polchinski's proof of the no-ghost theorem. In equation 4.4.19 (at the bottom of page 140 in the latest edition) he considers the following state (or rather map between states)

$$|\psi> = (1-S^{-1}U+S^{-1}US^{-1}U \cdots)\: |\psi_0>. \tag{4.4.19}$$

He claims that if $S|\psi_0> = 0$ then $(S+U)|\psi> = 0$ and I dont see that.

If I understand things correctly then the operator $(1-S^{-1}U+S^{-1}US^{-1}U \cdots)$ is supposed to be something like $S(S+U)^{-1}$ but I have two things that are tripping me up here. First of all lets imagine that $S,U,S+U$ were all invertible, then $(1-S^{-1}U+S^{-1}US^{-1}U \cdots) = S(S+U)^{-1}$. In that case we would have

$$(S+U)|\psi> = (S+U)S(S+U)^{-1}|\psi_0>.$$

But thats it because I cant commute the $S$ through a $U$ because they have different $N_{LC}$ charges.

Secondly all that clearly isn't the case because neither of $S,U,S+U$ are invertible. Now he makes the point that $S^{-1}U$ is still well defined, because U takes you out of the 0 eigenspace of S and so on the non-zero eigenspace of $S$ I can define an $S^{-1}$. But this leaves me confused as to how we then see that $(S+U)|\psi> = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM, I figured it out (I think)

I want $(S+U)|\psi> =S |\psi_0> $, realize that $(S+U) = S(1+S^{-1}U)$, choose $|\psi> = (1+S^{-1}U)^{-1}|\psi_0>$ and the rest follows